# How do I use scrapy re() selector?

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, scrapy

This is my regex :

```
".*\/(.*)\?ref"
```

This is my test string:

```
/product/sam/go-with-me?ref=popular
```

I can get :`go-with-me`
I did try on `https://regex101.com/#python`

But I don't know how to write with scrapy,
it get nothing

Here is my code:

```
for site in sites:
    title = sel.css("a::text").re(r".*\/(.*)\?ref")
    print title
    break
```

Comment: Can you share a sample HTML code containing the desired link? (or share the url to the web page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to say without seeing your real HTML input data, but you might just need to look into `href` attribute value instead of a text:

```
for site in sites:
    title = site.xpath(".//a/@href").re(r".*\/(.*)\?ref")
    print title
    break
```